# Alerting fragments - ContentProvider, Handler or Service?

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, android-handler

I am doing an application that has a thread always hearing on a specific UDP address/port for a custom messaging protocol. These need to be passed on to the fragments that change the UI accordingly, one case being update marker postition on a Maps API v2.
  The thred listening for UDP is legacy, I must to implementing one interface method that will be called when a message arrives.

UDP  --->  legacy listener  --->  interface method  --->  ?????  ---> UI fragments

What should I use for the ????? ?
I have looked into:

1. Services - I got the feeling it's the inverted concept since the fragments call the service and I need the fragments to be called only when a message arrives.
2. ContentProvider - Not a great fit as it is for structured data.
3. Handler - didn't understand how to structure the code to use it since I cannot pass the handler to the thread listening UDP and have to factor in the interface method.

Bonus points if there is a way to only call the fragment when specific types of message arrive. Each fragment is only interested in a subset of the types of messages in the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution is to communicate back to your UI fragment by getting a static reference to the object and passing it data
.
So in you Fragment you have a public method like

```
public static MyFragment getInstance(){

return mFragment;
}
```

and then you have a method like

```
public void updateUI(Data data){

//code to update the UI
}
```

So then in your interface method when you receive the data from your Legacy Listener you can just

```
MyFragment myFrag = MyFragment.getInstance();


myFrag.updateUI(data);
```

Its quite easy.

Otherwise I think the more correct approach is to use a Messenger and a Handler.